# Tkinter widgets placed incorrectly

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to create a frame with

- combobox
- then two labels
- and then another combobox.

Instead I get a frame with

- two comboboxes
- and then two labels

Tkinter widgets seem to be grouped by the widget type. Please advise how to place the widgets correctly. Thanks!

I am using Python 3.4 on Win 7 64 bit and Tcl/Tk version 8.6.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()

        self.combo1=ttk.Combobox(self)
        self.combo1["values"]=["1","2"]
        self.combo1.grid(row=1)

        self.lbl1=ttk.Label(text="AAA")
        self.lbl1.grid(row=2)

        self.lbl3=ttk.Label(text="BBB")
        self.lbl3.grid(row=3)

        self.combo2=ttk.Combobox(self)
        self.combo2["values"]=["3","4"]
        self.combo2.grid(row=4)

root=tk.Tk()
x=App()
```

[image: incorrect layout]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened because you didn't set the parent of your `Labels` to `self` (the frame), try changing your labels to this:

```
self.lbl1=ttk.Label(self, text="AAA")
...

self.lbl3=ttk.Label(self, text="BBB")
```

Previously they had used the default parent, which is `root`, so they appeared below your frame.